# Get unique values from multiple tables using query builder joins

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am able to view all the joined table values but the problem is that it is being duplicated. I have already used distinct in my controller.

I want to display the product, qty, and trans_amount of a transaction.

[image: Table View]

Controller:

```
$products = DB::table('transactions')
        ->join('transactions_prods', 'transactions_prods.trans_id', '=', 'transactions.id')
        ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'transactions_prods.prod_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'transactions.user_id')
        ->join('transactions_solds', 'transactions_solds.trans_id', '=', 'transactions.id')
        ->select('transactions_prods.prod_id as id', 
                 'transactions.type as Type', 
                 'products.prod_name as product_name', 
                 'transactions_prods.qty as qty',
                 'transactions.id as transid',
                 'users.id as user_id',
                 'transactions_solds.trans_amt as amount')
        ->where('transactions.type', '=', 'Sell')
        ->where('transactions.id', '=', $id)
        ->distinct()->get();

        return view('system.transactions.edit_transaction')->with('products', $products);
```

edit_transactions.blade.php

```
       <div class="panel-heading"><b>TransID: {{$products[0]->transid}}</b>
        <br>
        <b>CashierID: {{$products[0]->user_id}}</b>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body" style="overflow-x:auto;">

        <table id="data-table" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th valign="middle">ID</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Amt</th>
                    <th>Action</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($products as $product)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$product->qty}}</td>
                        <td>{{$product->amount}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">REMOVE</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Tables:

```
transactions
id | type | user_id

transactions_prods
id | trans_id | prod_id| qty

transactions_solds
id | trans_id | trans_amt | trans_scd

users
id | name | role_id | email | password
```

Comment: this is a LINQ question

Comment: Use Group by instead of distinct.

Comment: Group by what particular? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this on my own. thank you for all of your support. I merged the prod_id and qty into transactions_solds table and used distinct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is likely the join to the users table. This doesn't seem necessary based on the results you desire.

Comment: but even if i remove the users from the join it's still the same